# Making a class member array of objects in Python3

Tags: c#, python, list, class, tuples

I'm trying to create 3 custom classes in Python:

1. One for a "Property"
2. One for a "Building"
3. One for a "Tenant"

In reality, a property can have multiple buildings on it, and each building can have multiple tenants. So, in trying to code that in Python, I haven't found a clear way to have a class member variable which is an array of objects of the other classes' type. In C# I did it using C# Lists, as follows:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Building> Buildings = new List<Building>();
}

public class Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Tenant> Tenants = new List<Tenant>();
}

public class Tenant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SF { get; set; }
    public decimal Rent { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this in Python? Actually I've been kind of confused in general how to 'declare' class member variables.. it seems like the closest thing to declaring them is setting them to a value for the first time in the `__init__` constructor, which feels odd to me. Anyways I'm new to Python so maybe that's just how it's done.

I've read a little bit about how tuples and lists are used in Python, so I'm guessing the solution would have something to do with that, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Thanks any help is appreciated

Comment: What was unclear in the python class tutorials you have read?

Comment: Setting a class member variable is as easy as typing `self.xxxxx = abc` in the `__init__` function.

Comment: I'm not sure how you've managed to do any Python at all without realising that you don't declare variables at all, and that lists can contain anything, even non-homogenous items.